# Searching column for instances of a string. TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

Tags: python, string, pandas

I'm cleaning up some twitter API data and I'm looking for find an instance of a string.In this case 'big data' is used an example. But my error says I need to have integers not strings.

This is odd because the column I'm looking at 'Text' are strings and not integers. And I need them to be strings so I can search for instances of the text I'm looking for.

```
DataSet.head()

     tweetID    Text                                             coordinates    followerCount   friendsCount    Location    Name    Lang    screenName  createdAt   timeZone
0   1514313588  #Analytics #Jobs: #Data Scientist @ https://t....   None    760 2029    None    claap   en  goCLAAP Thu Jun 13 20:06:03 +0000 2013  None
1   3161843418  RT @asokan_telecom: How 2 Manage Sucessful #Bi...   None    564 0   None    RA Fisher   en  dataproblems    Sat Apr 18 04:15:08 +0000 2015  None
2   95143217    Sensors &amp; big-data analytics measure &amp;...   None    422 306 Singapore   Stacey Albert   en  StaceyGAlbert   Mon Dec 07 05:32:49 +0000 2009  Singapore
3   3319297545  RT @BurtchWorks: Looking for a Data Scientist ...   None    165 161 Evanston, IL    emazeMe Evanston    en  eMazingEvanston Thu Jun 11 17:59:22 +0000 2015  None
4   26489112    Upcoming webinar: Interactive Business Intelli...   None    1276    1677    North America/EMEA  Perficient Life Sci en  Perficient_LS   Wed Mar 25 12:50:21 +0000 2009  Central Time (US & Canada)
```

I'm trying to pull instances of strings from the "Text" column with this:

```
tweets['big data'] = DataSet['Text'].str.contains(r'big data', na=False)
```

But I get this error:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

But that does not make sense, and I need this column to be strings to find an instance of the string.

What am I missing here?

Comment: What type of your `tweets`?

Comment: Thanks @AntonProtopopov I solved it!

Answer (score 0):

Solved it thanks to AntonProtopopov. I did not name my dataFrame correctly.

```
DataSet['big data'] = DataSet['Text'].str.contains(r'big data', na=False)
```